# Rotate base64 string Nativescript-Vue

Tags: image, vue.js, rotation, base64, nativescript

I would like to rotate an image 90 degrees. I am working with Nativescript-Vue and the image has the form of a base64 string. I tried the following:

```
let newImage = new Image();

let imgSource = new ImageSource();
imgSource.fromBase64(base64string);
imgSource.rotationAngle = 90;

newImage.imageSource = imgSource;
newImage.rotate;

let newBase64 = newImage.imageSource;toBase64String("jpg");
```

which does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't you use css?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommending rotating the image in CSS, if you can:

```
.myBtn {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}
```